# Unable to install flask-ask

Tags: flask-ask

I am trying to install flask-ask using pip(3). Getting the following error

`from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_requirements'`

I cloned the source code to my machine and tried 'python setup.py install' but getting the same error. Seems there's some compatibility issue with pip but not able to put my finger on it

Any pointers - kindly help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to install `flask-ask` on my machine using pip 10.0.0 and I got the same errors as yours. This is what I did to overcome the problem, just downgrade your pip version to 9.0.3 and you'll get the module without an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response..worked pretty well..bit worried though if other code will work with the same version

Comment: Isn't there any other solution, My pip got upgraded to 19.1.1, and I am not even able to install from source using `python setup.py build/install`